# Why am I getting Class NotFound Exception using Tomcat in my webapp?

Tags: json, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using Gson Library 2.8.0 to convert JSON strings into Java Hashmap, Maven as a build system, 
Tomcat to run my code as webapp.
IDE: IntelliJ Idea

The issue is whenever I run my code, execution stop and throws Class NotFound Exception.

Details as follows:

**Tomcat Localhost logs ==>**

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
>     at Test.doGet(Test.java:13)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

**Code ==>**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }";

    HashMap<String,Object> map=gson.fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println("This is the converted Gson result\n" +map);

    }
}
```

Comment: `com.google.gson.Gson` is not available at runtime

Comment: are you running  on tomcat in  intelliJ or are you deploying to tomcat manually?

Comment: add your `pom.xml` too

Comment: @secret super star Yes I am using tomcat in intelliJ. And what you mean by Gson is not available at runtime? Can You explain?

Comment: It means, while you run the application, the jvm is not able find the class `Gson` class in classpath and hence causing the issue. Try to clean the tomcat and run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue is solved by putting Gson library files into the lib folder
 of Tomcat.**